# @PostLoad on an @Embeddable in JPA 2?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the problem that my `@PostLoad` method on an `@Embeddable` is not invoked.

But I do not know, if it should work and there is a bug more missconfiguration somewhere, or I it should not work because `@PostLoad` is only for `@Entity`s?

I did not find an concrete statement about `@PostLoad` in `@Embeddable` in the [JSR](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html).

> 3.5.1 Lifecycle Callback Methods
>
> Entity lifecycle callback methods can be defined on an entity listener
>   class and/or directly on an entity class or mapped superclass.

I do not know if this statement include `@Embeddable` or not.

*My Persistence Provider is Eclipselink.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity callbacks and listeners are not currently processed for Embeddables.  This is probably inline with the spec, as they are called "Entity" callbacks, also the orm.xml does not allow them for embeddable.

But, EclipseLink does support events for embeddables, so there is no reason we could not support this, so please log a bug on EclipseLink.

You should be able to define a DescriptorEventListener for your embeddable using a DescriptorCustomizer, the PostLoad callback is mapped to postBuild and postClone.

Comment: Is there any chance this is also available in some form for Hibernate ?